# Relation between energy, frequency and wavelength

Tags: optics, energy, reflection, frequency, absorption

Frequency $f$ and wavelength $\lambda$ of light don't alter after reflection. If that is the case, then energy should also not alter after reflection as $E=h f$. But energy gets altered after reflection. How is that possible?

Comment: Why do you think the energy gets altered after reflection?

Comment: @mmeent I thought energy would not change. But fact says it does.

Comment: What facts? The only way energy can change in reflection is if a) the mirror is moving (but then the frequency and wavelength is changing) b) if there is partial absorbtion.

Comment: Actually [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/373578/249968) of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/373577/249968) does seem to answer your question!

Comment: @Johan Liebert Thanks. I guess I understood.

Comment: @mmeent Thanks! I was talking about partial absorption.